# How do I import from a subdirectory?

Tags: python, import, path, osx-mavericks, pythonpath

This is a simplification of a problem that exists in a complex project. 
In a folder called `root_test`, I have a folder called `test`, containing `tester.py`. I also have (in `test`) a `modules` directory (empty) containing a `lib` directory, which holds `logger.py`. Dir structure below.

```
|-root_test
|---test/
|-----tester.py
|-----__init__.py
|-----modules/
|-------__init__.py
|-------lib/
|---------__init__.py
|---------logger.py
```

alternatively, run from `root_test`:

```
 $ ls
test

 $ ls test/
__init__.py  modules      tester.py

 $ ls test/modules/
__init__.py  lib

 $ ls test/modules/lib/
__init__.py  logger.py
```

`tester.py` is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys, os

# allow running without installing
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), '..'))

import test.modules.lib.logger
```

but when I try and run it from `root_test` dir, I get the following error:

```
 $ python test/tester.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test/tester.py", line 8, in <module>
    import test.modules.lib.logger
ImportError: cannot import name logger
```

This doesn't happen on my other laptop, and their `$PYTHONPATH`s are identical:

```
 $ echo $PYTHONPATH
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/:
```

Comment: `logging` != `logger`...

Comment: Seems like `a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error.`

Comment: Sorry - that's a typo. Fixed. Problem persists though.

Comment: If you do "import modules.lib.logger" without the test, you get same error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that there was a module installed called tester. And even though I was explicitly running `python ~/test/tester.py`, it still ran the installed module instead. Removing that module fixed the problem.